# discrete mathematics , sequences, characteristic equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, discrete-mathematics

Today in my discrete mathematics class we started combinatorics and also solved some some recurrence relation sequences using the characteristic equation. So my question is can you guys point me to some exercises about recurrence relation sequences using the characteristic equation, because in my text book there are any, but there will be problems of this kind on my exam. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search "Introductory Combinatorics 6th edition by Richard Brualdi" chapter $7.3$ and $7.4$, "Discrete Mathematics with Combinatorics and Graph Theory by Kenneth Rosen", and "Discrete Mathematics with Graph Theory by Edgar G. Goodaire and Michael M. Parmenter" chapter $5.2$, $5.3$, and $5.4$. All of these books have many problems of the type you seek.

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way i also found some problems in "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications".

Comment: No problem. That book is great too.